# Rasterization of polygons, calculation of the area covered

Tags: raster, r, rasterization

In R environment I have (1) a SpatialPolygonDataFrame with number of polygons: `polys`; (2) raster grid of resolution 10'000 m: `grid`. Both of them are in the LAEA coordination system.

What I need is to get the area covered by polygons in each individual grid cell. I tried the following function:

```
r_area_covered <- rasterize(polys, grid, getCover = T)
```

It basically works and the result is roughly ok. However, in more detailed view it is quite inconsistent. Some polygons were ignored while other polygons of smaller sizes were considered for the calculation.

My questions are: where can be the mistake and how to prevent it? Do I have other options to do this in R.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Check if the polygon layer have valid geometries. If there are some invalid geometries, maybe they are skipped in calculation. Look at `cleangeo` package

Comment: It is complicated to prepare some sample data in this case, but the geometry is valid, I have checked that. I will try to prepare something in case I don't get any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`coverage_fraction`](https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/reference/coverage_fraction.html) in the [`exactextractr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/index.html) package to get this directly. Unlike `raster::rasterize`, the result is not affected by the position of the polygons or their size relative to the grid cell size.

This provides you with the fraction (0-1) of each cell that is covered by the polygons. You can then multiply this by the cell area. By default, it produces one raster per input feature. If you want to find the fraction of a cell that is covered by *any* polygon, you can combine the polygons into a single feature first.

Note also that `exactextractr` deals with `sf` objects rather than `sp` objects, so you'll need to load the `sf` package first.

```
r_frac_covered <- coverage_fraction(grid, st_combine(st_as_sf(polys)))[[1]]
```

Comment: This really is the way to go and exactextractr is written in C++. The easiest way to coerce an sp to sf class is to use the method from sf, which is best called using `as(x, "sf")` and to go the other way `as(x, "Spatial)`

Comment: This is the solution! It is quite accurate and at the same time really fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem may arise from the way getCover works and the resolution of your grid.

From the `rasterize()` function [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-12/topics/rasterize) on getCover:

> The fraction covered is estimated by dividing each cell into 100 subcells and determining presence/absence of the polygon **in the center** of each subcell.

If your raster has a resolution of 10,000 m, each subcell will have a resolution of 100m. That is still pretty big and a polygon could easily miss the centre. So for example, a polygon of just 2x2 m happening to be dead centre of a subcell would get picked up, but a larger polygon of 25x25 m near the corner of the subcell wouldn't.

[image: Presence/absence of polygons in subcells]

I'm not sure what the most elegant way of solving this is. But perhaps you could create a finer grid for this step, and aggregate back to your desired resolution. The finer the resolution, the more accurate the cover estimate would become. Depending on the amount of data you have this might be quite slow though!

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem and for the suggestion of the solution. However, the solution suggested by @dbaston is slightly more elegant.