# Rasterization of polygons - area covered different categories

Tags: raster, r, rasterization

I have a Shapefile of habitat type across Great Britain - I have split this large Shapefile into smaller categories by filtering in R.

For each of these smaller categories I used the coverage_fraction (method here: [Rasterization of polygons, calculation of the area covered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359277/rasterization-of-polygons-calculation-of-the-area-covered)) to convert to a raster and work out the ha of each habitat category in my Great Britain grid cells (1km2 / 100 ha cells). For each habitat the range of ha is always between 0 and 100 - which is correct.

My issue is when I look at the sum of the habitats the total ha often exceeds 100 ha value - which is incorrect.

I have checked the resolution / extent are fine. I have also tried different methods e.g. rasterize / rasterizeGeom. I have also considered the issue may arise when splitting my shapefiles - I have looked at tools in ArcMap such the dissolve tool - but I am still running into this issue.

If anyone has any advice to help resolve this issue please let me know.

Comment: Is the feature geometry of your habitat types SINGLE or MULTI polygon. If you are using multipart geometry things can get quite wonky, This can be dealt with by exploding the geometry into single part using `st_cast(x, POLYGON)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, so my original large shapefile (and the smaller habitat type shapefiles) have sfc MULTI polygon geometry. I will give the st_cast code a try

Comment: I tried using st_cast, but even with this I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Could the problem be linked to the boundaries of the different shapefiles?

Comment: I would expect to see values above 100 if your habitat polygons have overlaps. Is that possible?